# Is it a good idea to check if prime candidate is of residue class $1$ modulo $4$ in Rabin-Miller Test?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, quadratic-residues, primality-test

We represent $p - 1$ in the form of $2^K \cdot Q$ where $Q$ is odd. After that we select any residue class $A$ for the primality test.

If $z \equiv A^Q \not\equiv \pm 1$ under modulo $p$, we need to square the $z$ at most $K - 1$ times until we obtain the residue class $-1$. If this step fails then either Fermat's Little Theorem not holds or $1$ have a non-trivial square root. In each case $p$ is composite.

So, here is my idea to improve this test: Before starting to square the $z$, we should check if $-1$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$, since otherwise we can't obtain it as a square. Hence we should check if $p$ is of residue class $1$ modulo $4$.

Can we make the test more efficient this way?

Comment: You mean if $p \equiv 3 \bmod 4$ and $A^{2^r Q} \equiv -1 \bmod p$ then $p$ is composite. Generalizing that you propose, once $A^{2^r Q} \equiv b \bmod p$,  if $b$ is small enough, to factor $b$  and find if its prime factors are quadratic residues $\bmod p$, possibly disproving $p$ is prime. I would also compare with the [number field sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_number_field_sieve)

Comment: Yes. This is exactly what i mean